# Jenkins azure deploy error: az login error issuer

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, azure-web-app-service

I have my groovy script to deploy a simple api(nodejs) on azure app service.

```
pipeline {
agent none
environment {
    //app service
    DEV_SERVICE_NAME  = 'xxxxxx'
    ...
    ...

    AZURE_DEV_USER_ID  = 'abcdefghijk'
    AZURE_DEV_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxx'
    AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_TENANT_ID = 'xxxxxx'
}
stage('Service Deployment (DEV)'){
   agent { label 'master'}
   steps {
     //Install all packages
     bat "npm i --production"
     ..
     ..
     bat "CALL az login --service-principal --username $env.AZURE_DEV_USER_ID --password $env.AZURE_DEV_PASSWORD --tenant $env.AZURE_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_TENANT_ID"
     ..
     ..
}
```

so, when jenkins builds, fails, and print an error

```
C:\jenkins\workspace\loud_feature-deploy-api-on-azure@2>CALL az login --service-principal --username 
null --password null --tenant null 
usage: az login [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]
            [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml,yamlc,none}]
            [--query JMESPATH] [--username USERNAME] [--password PASSWORD]
            [--service-principal] [--tenant TENANT]
            [--allow-no-subscriptions] [-i] [--use-device-code]
            [--use-cert-sn-issuer]
az login: error: 'issuer'
```

so, I have 2 questions.

1. Why prints null for env values?
2. Why this error ?, I read the [MSFT doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#manage-service-principal-roles) and command should be work fine. so, I don't know, What may be happening, null values are suspect...

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to reproduce your issue by following [this Jenkins document](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/) but was successfully able to echo environment variables that are set.

Regarding `AZURE_DEV_PASSWORD` variable in your case, I believe that its not better approach to have secure information like password in the pipeline so I would suggest you to just add an Azure service principal to Jenkins credential and then write an Jenkins pipeline script by having `withCredentials([azureServicePrincipal('SERVICEPRINCIPALCREDENTIALID')])` and then by using `sh` part to have Azure CLI command to deploy api(nodejs) on Azure app service as appropriate.

For more information with regards to it, please refer [this Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/execute-cli-jenkins-pipeline#add-azure-service-principal-to-jenkins-credential) or [this Jenkins plugin article](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-credentials/) or [this Jenkins blog](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/08/10/kubernetes-with-pipeline-acs/).